# read, fread partial reads

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, fread

I can't seem to find info about this in the documentation.

The `read` system call documentation says it may read less than specified.
Does `read`attempt to read several times?

I know that `fread` is a wrapper for `read`. When I invoke `fread`, is it possible that it will read from the stream several times until it gets 0 or reads specified bytes, or will it only attempt to read once?

I am reading from a char device created in my kernel module, it transfers info from a data structure and supports partial reads. I am interested in reading all of the data until it returns 0.

thanks

Comment: Depends on whether the "stream" is a file, or something else.

Comment: You are somewhat mixing apples and oranges. `read` will read the number of bytes you tell it to. When you are reading from a file, that's not a problem, the bytes are there (unless EOF is encountered first). So in that case, read may return less than requested. However, when you are reading from a network connection, there is no guarantee that any bytes will be there until they are sent by the remote host. So in that case, it is very common from `read` to return less than requested until the bytes become available.

Comment: @user3386109  In my case it is a char device I created in a kernel module. It supports partial reads (I maintain an offset and write the appropriate data to the userspace buffer) but I don't know on user side if I need to call read on the device in a loop or it is handled inside

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general idea of `read` is that it returns as soon as some data is available¹. From an application's perspective, that's all you can assume.

If you're implementing the `read` callback in a kernel driver, it's up to you when `read` decides to return some data. But applications will² expect that `read` calls may be partial, and they should call `read` in a loop if they really need a certain number of bytes. Some applications want `read` not to block, so it would be a bad idea to block in a `read` call if some data is available.

The `fread` function blocks until it's read as many bytes as were requested, until it's reached the end of the file, or until an error occurs. It works by calling `read` in a loop.

¹ <sub>Whether and when `read` may return 0 bytes is beyond the scope of this answer.</sub> 
² <sub>Or at least should. Buggy applications do exist.</sub>

Comment: In particular, like all stdio read functions, fread is specified to behave *as if* by repeated calls to fgetc until certain conditions are met.

Comment: Question for detail clarification: Is it correct that the reference for `fread` behaving as written here is [here in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) where it says: _"fread() shall return the number of elements successfully read which is less than nitems only if a read error or end-of-file is encountered"_, or are there other specs that implementors use as a reference?

Comment: @nh2 `fread` is a standard C function (unlike `read` which is a Unix/POSIX function). See for example [C11 §7.21.8.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).