# Behavior of fread when only a partial record is available before the end of file

Tags: c, language-lawyer, fread

I work on what can be seen as a C interpreter that detects all undefined behaviors in the program it interprets. While using this interpreter to find bugs in a legacy open-source C application, I was puzzled by the following behavior:

The legacy application expected a 10-byte header that it needed it its entirety in order to do further work. It was correctly calling `fread(buffer, 10, 1, f);`. Incorrectly, it did not assign the result of the `fread` call, and started parsing the buffer right away.

When this `fread` was applied on a file with less than 10 bytes available, what happened was that `buffer` was partially filed with the available data. The interpreter, as it is designed to, detected that an uninitialized part of the buffer was used later and warned about that and I was able to trace the problem to the result of `fread` being discarded.

It puzzled me for one minute that the `fread` written by my colleagues had partially filled the buffer, even though it was going to return `0` eventually, and I wondered if this could be improved. Obviously some implementations do read into the buffer and in the end return the number of read record as `return n_bytes / __size;`, letting the division round down, in this case to `0`. But I wondered if other implementations might only write to `buffer` if an entire record is available, and leave it entirely uninitialized otherwise.

In practice, on the two Unices that I have at hand, `fread` behaves the same way as the model implementation written by my colleagues:

```
~ $ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buffer[11] = "0000000000";

int main(void) {

  FILE *f = fopen("aaaa", "r");
  if (!f) exit(1);
  int r = fread(buffer, 10, 1, f);
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
~ $ gcc t.c && ./a.out 
aaaa000000
~ $ uname -a
Darwin tis-laptop-6.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Sun Jun  2 20:26:31 PDT 2019; root:xnu-3789.73.50~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

The test program also produces the same result on Linux with Glibc (the file `aaaa` contains `aaaa`).

It would be unreasonably costly to analyse what happens in each of the cases “`fread` partially fills the last record” and “`fread` leaves the last partial record untouched in the buffer” in the interpreter, but we could make the part of the buffer that should have received the record for which there is only partial data uninitialized, to prevent the interpreted C program to rely on it. But that in turn would be puzzling when `fread` is passed an already initialized buffer.

So I find myself wondering whether the behavior that the interpreter's `fread` currently has, and that macOS and Linux/Glibc also have, is guaranteed (in which case everything is fine).

I have found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53452824/139746). [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452824/read-fread-partial-reads#comment93783175_53453140) seems to indicate that the `fread` behavior I observed in all three implementations is the only possible one, but I would like an explicit confirmation (or not) that `fread` can be assumed to read all the characters available up to `size * nmemb` even if the number of characters available is not a multiple of `size`.

Comment: If you switch around the `fread(buffer, 10, 1, f);` to `fread(buffer, 1, 10, f);` then it is very cheap to determine how much of the buffer was filled.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, but then again, `fread(buffer, 10, 1, f);` is the standard idiom for “give me 10 characters or give me nothing, I'm not interested in 5 or 9”, and it's good that people use it this way (less good that they don't check the result of `fread`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (§7.19.8.2) and [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (§7.21.8.2) define `fread()` with the following description:

> The `fread` function  reads,  into  the  array  pointed  to  by `ptr`, up to `nmemb` elements whose  size  is  specified  by `size`,  from  the  stream  pointed  to  by `stream`.  For  each object, `size` calls  are  made  to  the `fgetc` function  and  the  results  stored,  in  the  order read,  in  an  array  of `unsigned char` exactly  overlaying  the  object.  The  file  position indicator for the stream (if defined) is advanced by the number of characters successfully read.  If an error occurs, the resulting value of the file position indicator for the stream is indeterminate.  If a partial element is read, its value is indeterminate.

That last bit should clear your doubts:

> If a partial element is read, its value is indeterminate.

So, even though all the implementations you see appear to behave "nicely", you cannot rely on that, as it is implementation-dependent behavior that the standard does not define. A program that wishes to read a partial element (if the file contains one) should use a `size` of `1` and check the return value. Indeed, if a program does not do this and instead reads with `size > 1` and `nmemb = 1`, it wouldn't even have the ability to distinguish between initialized and unitialized data into the buffer in the case of a last partial element.

Comment: This is great because making the partial element explicitly indeterminate is exactly what the C interpreter I am working on can do and what it should do according to the C standard sentence that you have found.

Comment: @PascalCuoq yep, I would say that what your interpreter is doing is right.

Comment: @PascalCuoq though the actual cause for undefined behavior here is simply "read from uninitialized memory".

Comment: @PascalCuoq hmm I see, yes, marking the whole 10 bytes as uninitialized memory is definitely better for such a tool. Even though they are not "uninitialized" in the strict meaning of the word, their content is unknown and implementation-defined, the program should not depend on it.

Comment: I am interpreting “indeterminate” in the technical sense of the C standard (something that can exist in memory but that it's UB-ish to access and use in a computation—I actually have a blog post somewhere about the meaning of “indeterminate” throughout C standards). Currently the interpreter has two kinds of indeterminate markers: “uninitialized” and “dangling pointer”. It has been valuable to distinguish them for more understandable diagnostics. I have been thinking of adding “padding” for a while. “Partial record of fread” seems a bit specific but why not?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Note that it's only indeterminare if a partial element was read. If it stopped (at EOF) due to an exact multiple of `size` bytes being available, in quantity less than `nmemb`, then the next byte of the destination buffer is not indeterminate but untouched.